# Print WebView/WebEngine with auto page break

Tags: java, html, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have some HTML text like

```
<h1>lorem... </h1>
<b> Lorem text going on...
```

and I want to print the HTML on any printer

```
WebEngine webEngine = WebView.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent(html);
webEngine.print(javafx.PrinterJob);
```

But the result is one page cut off at the botten...
The print function of chrome has the functionality I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I get this solution for my case. I'm using a `JEditorPane`

```
 JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
 editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
 editorPane.setText("<html>...");
 editorPane.print(null, null, false, javax.print.PrintService, null, false);
```

And in now there are auto page breaks